# How to provide write permission for specific tables in PostgreSQL?

Tags: postgresql, permissions, postgresql-11

I have a user with read-only access in my PostgreSQL 11.
How can I give them access to write/edit data in some of the database tables, e.g. `Table1` and `Table2` only?

I don't want them to change the DB schema or table structure.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use [`GRANT`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-grant.html):

```
GRANT INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE ON table1 TO some_user;
```

You may want to read about basics of the [Postgres privilege system in the manual](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/ddl-priv.html). One essential quote:

> The right to modify or destroy an object is inherent in being the
> object's owner, and cannot be granted or revoked in itself. (However,
> like all privileges, that right can be inherited by members of the
> owning role; see [Section 22.3](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/role-membership.html).)